# How to change the color of a table view cell dynamically

Tags: ios

How to change the colour of the table view cell dynamically .
I want to achieve something like shown in screenshot please suggest.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: swift or objectiv-c?

Comment: Both answers you have gotten have given you ways to assign colors based on a cell's indexPath. The thing you need to do is figure out what colors you want for the cells, and how to generate those colors. Do you want the specific colors you show in your sample image? 

I'd suggest taking your sample colors into a photo editor like Photoshop, sampling the RGB values of each, and coming up with either an array of color values (as in @tejendrasingh's answer) or a function that generates those color values for each step (as in Adrian's answer).

Comment: How many cells will have you have total? You need to spread out the color change from the start to the end cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to do:

I give a demo below:

[image]

1. Firstly, drag a `tableView` to `vc`:

[image]

2. Secondly, set the `tableView`'s delegate and dataSource:

[image]

3. The third step, in your `vc`, set the `data`:

   import UIKit

   class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

   @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

   var cellCount:Int! = 6

   var cus_color:UIColor  = UIColor.init(red: 35 / 255.0, green: 204/255.0, blue: 216.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       self.tableView.separatorStyle = .none
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

       return 100
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       return cellCount
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       let cell = UITableViewCell() // or your custom cell

       let perLevel:CGFloat = CGFloat(1.0) / CGFloat(self.cellCount)

       cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(red: 35 / 255.0, green: 204/255.0, blue: 216.0/255.0, alpha: (perLevel + CGFloat(indexPath.row) * perLevel))

       return cell
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       self.tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: false)
   }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UITableViewCell property **backgroundColor** to set cell color dynamically.

Example-

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell* cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    }
    //cellColorHolder is UIColor object type array.
    cell.backgroundColor = (UIColor*)[cellColorHolder objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```